# spring MongoRepository Query regex

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I´m looking to use a regular expresion using MongoRepository inside a Query annotation. The only information that I found so far is a Chinese post but do not explain how make it works, and I´m not sure if is what I´m looking for.

@Query("{ 'name':{'$regex':?2,'$options':'i'}, sales': {'$gte':?1,'$lte':?2}}")
public Page findByNameAndAgeRange(String name,double ageFrom,double ageTo,Pageable page);

Somebody know if it possible use a specific regex in the query?

Regards.

Comment: I already saw that with the expresion @Query("{ 'name':{'$regex':?2,'$options':''} without "i" works, I dont know why the people use that letter in there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> i toggles case insensitivity, and allows all letters in the pattern to match upper and lower cases.

Read more about $regex in [MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/).

In your query it looks like you have mixed up something with parameters order (?2 in name regex). I believe it should be:

```
@Query("{ 'name':{$regex:?0,$options:'i'}, sales': {$gte:?1,$lte:?2}}") 
public Page findByNameAndAgeRange(String name,double ageFrom,double ageTo,Pageable page);
```

Comment: Another Question, If I want use $or with the regex patter cannot I use this query?  @Query{$or: ['title' : { '$regex' : "19", '$options' : ''}, 'description' : { '$regex' : "19", '$options' : ''}]}  I dont know why but is not working

Comment: I forgot an extra {} @Query{$or: [{'title' : { '$regex' : "19", '$options' : ''}}, {'description' : { '$regex' : "19", '$options' : ''}}]}

Comment: here the regex passed as String ends up as String in the query, so the regex wont work